# suddenly I can't logging ASP.Net Site

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iis

I deployed asp. Site in IIS 6 in my office network. It is working properly until yesterday. Now I browse host url .  It’s load home page.  But I enter login details its again prompt login page. Then I enter wrong condition that same thing happen (no display invalid username or password massage).

Same code working properly in my local environment. Please advise this. Thanks.

Comment: Check your event log. See if you can find help from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advised to system administrator to restart the server machine, Now it's working properly.